# Power outage during apt-get upgrade broke apt-get commands

Tags: apt, 18.04, package-management, kernel

I have a server running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. This morning I ran an `apt upgrade` and during it, the server lost power. Once it was restored, I logged in and noticed there were 2 packages "not fully installed or removed". I tried running `apt-get autoremove`, explicit `apt-get remove` commands, and numerous solutions found online that I can't remember at the moment.

Nothing seems to help, and I am unable to upgrade/install packages due to apt erring at the corrupt packages. They are kernel packages:

```
linux-image-4.15.0-50-generic
linux-image-4.15.0-51-generic
```

Here is the output of `apt-get autoremove`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-4.15.0-50-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 8,323 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
(Reading database ... 144087 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-4.15.0-50-generic (4.15.0-50.54) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-50-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/x-grub-legacy-ec2:
Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
/etc/default/grub: line 12: net.ifnames=0: command not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/x-grub-legacy-ec2 exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-50-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-4.15.0-50-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.15.0-50-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: One simple and easy-to-remember way is to reinstall the package (`sudo apt install --reinstall linux-image-4.15.0-50-generic`) then remove it (`sudo apt remove linux-image-4.15.0-50-generic`). There are more complicated ways if this fails.

Comment: Note that you also have a warning: `3 not fully installed or removed`. Keep an eye on that. If the kernel cleanup does not bring that number down to 0, then investigate further.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get the packages removed and gone. This was what I thought was causing my lighttpd install to break, but it still isn't working. I suppose I'll create a thread on their forums for further assistance. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Running a series of `apt-get autoremove` and `apt-get autoclean` commands after manually deleting `.deb` files seems to have cleared it up.

Comment: next time you run into this you can also try this command sudo dpkg --configure   -a  it sometimes will clear the problem.